# Pandasで条件に当てはまる列だけ同じ変換をしたい

Tags: python, pandas

Pandasで条件に当てはまる列だけ同じ変換を施したく、以下のコードを書いていますが
can't assign to function callのSyntax Errorが出てしまいます。

```
df.str.contains("x") = df.str.contains("x").apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 1 else 0)
```

どう改良すればよろしいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

条件は、「文字列"x"がカラム名に含まれる場合、そのカラムの値がもし1でなければ0を代入する」という内容でしょうか。

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "colx": [1,2,3],
    "coly": [4,5,6],
    "colz": [7,8,9],
})


# AS-IS:
# |    |   colx |   coly |   colz |
# |---:|-------:|-------:|-------:|
# |  0 |      1 |      4 |      7 |
# |  1 |      2 |      5 |      8 |
# |  2 |      3 |      6 |      9 |
#
# TO-BE:
# colx の index1と2の値が0に変わる
# |    |   colx |   coly |   colz |
# |---:|-------:|-------:|-------:|
# |  0 |      1 |      4 |      7 |
# |  1 |      0 |      5 |      8 |
# |  2 |      0 |      6 |      9 |

# 1. カラム毎にループ
for col in df:

    # 2. もし文字列"x"がカラム名に含まれる場合
    if "x" in col:

        # 3. そのカラムの値が1でなければ0を代入する
        df.loc[:, col] = df.loc[:, col].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 1 else 0)
```

---

`str`アクセサは値に対する条件のため、以下のようなときに使います：

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "colx": ["one", "two", "three"],
    "coly": ["four", "five", "six"],
    "colz": ["seven", "eight", "nine"],
})

# AS-IS:
# |    | colx   | coly   | colz   |
# |---:|:-------|:-------|:-------|
# |  0 | one    | four   | seven  |
# |  1 | two    | five   | eight  |
# |  2 | three  | six    | nine   |
#
# TO-BE:
# 値に"t"が含まれる場合、その値を"X"にする。
# |    | colx   | coly   | colz   |
# |---:|:-------|:-------|:-------|
# |  0 | one    | four   | seven  |
# |  1 | X      | five   | X      |
# |  2 | X      | six    | nine   |


for col in df:
    df.loc[df[col].str.contains("t"), col] = "X"
```

参考：
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Answer (score 1):

条件を `loc` に指定して当てはまる列を抽出し、`applymap` で変換します。

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "colx": [0, 1, 2],
    "coly": [0, 1, 2],
    "colz": [0, 1, 2],
})

print(df)
#    colx  coly  colz               
# 0     0     0     0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     2     2     2

# columns containing "x"
columns_x = df.columns.str.contains("x")

# map to apply
f = lambda x: 1 if x == 1 else 0

df.loc[:, columns_x] = df.loc[:, columns_x].applymap(f)

print(df)
#    colx  coly  colz
# 0     0     0     0
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     0     2     2
```